# Logic behind how Next.js builds dynamic pages using the app router system?

Tags: javascript, next.js, bundle

#### Background: `dynamic` pages

I have some large pages in my Next.js app currently (app router style), and am trying to debug why the pages are so large, and it's *hard* to say the least.

```
Route (app)                               Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                     3.29 kB         846 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                           142 B          86.5 kB
├ ○ /my/first/page                        1.56 kB         414 kB
├ λ /my/dynamic/page/[x]                  57.8 kB         636 kB
├ λ /my/other/page                        326 kB         1.32 MB
...
+ First Load JS shared by all             86.3 kB
  ├ chunks/4422-2c92fefc06002e18.js       30.3 kB
  ├ chunks/65b6c8ea-4ad97acde17233b9.js   53.6 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)           2.38 kB
```

One of my pages, the `/my/dynamic/page/[x]`, has this in it:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const ACTUAL_PAGE = {
  a: dynamic(() => import("~/components/page/A")),
  b: dynamic(() => import("~/components/page/B")),
  c: dynamic(() => import("~/components/page/C")),
  d: dynamic(() => import("~/components/page/D")),
  // .. up to t, 20 different styles of pages, under the same URL.
};

export default function Page({ params }) {
  const ActualPage = ACTUAL_PAGE[params.x]
  return <ActualPage />
}
```

##### Sidenote: URL structure

I need this because I have these routes:

```
/convert/ttf/otf
/convert/png/jpg
/convert/rgb/hex
/convert/other/stuff
```

So I have a `FontConverter` page, `ImageConverter`, etc., 20 different types of converters, using the same URL system. I could do this:

```
/convert/font/ttf/otf
/convert/image/png/jpg
/convert/color/rgb/hex
/convert/some/other/stuff
```

But I don't want to do that... I like the simplicity of the URL structure I have.

#### Observation: `dynamic` subpages add to build size

When I comment out all but 1 `ACTUAL_PAGE` from above, it goes down to 400kb (still have more to figure out why my pages are so large). Each page I comment back in, it goes up by roughly 80kb:

- 1 page: 400kb
- 2 pages: 480kb
- 3 pages: 560kb
- 4 pages: 640kb

#### Assumption: `dynamic` pages aren't included in the build?

I assumed that all my `dynamic` pages weren't included in the build? But obviously they are somehow... Because commenting one in at a time slowly increases the final `First Load JS` in the top `λ /my/dynamic/page/[x]` log.

### Question

How does `dynamic` work with the output bundles? How does it change `First Load JS`? Also, what exactly is the difference between `Size` and `First Load JS`? (I haven't seen that in the docs yet).

I noticed that using `const Component = await import("~/components/page/A");` in a switch statement, like:

```
switch (params.x) {
  case "a": {
    const Component = (await import("~/components/page/A")).default;
    return <Component />;
  }
  case "b": {
    const Component = (await import("~/components/page/B")).default;
    return <Component />;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Also resulted in the same behavior, of `First Load JS` incrementing every page I added. So somehow the build/bundle is including my sub-imports intelligently.

How does it work?